# vulcanize for angular.dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

There is [vulcanize](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) like tool for polymer.dart (done by polymer transformer), that nicely puts all the imported components inline and makes it easy to serve the app by reducing the number of round trips to server. Is there any tool like vulcanize for angular.dart projects? esp. the one that can pull all the component's html into a single file and make it easy for deploying angular.dart app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [template-cache-transformer](https://farata.github.io/dart-template-cache-transformer/). From it's home page:

```
The Template Cache Transformer generates the template cache and 
optionally merges the CSS and HTML of AngularDart components into
a hosting Web page.
```

Answer (score 2):

AngularDart has the [template_cache_generator](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/bin/template_cache_generator.dart) which creates a Dart file to pre-populate Angular's template cache.

As far as I know, we have not done to work to include the template cache generator in the Angular transformer group.  There is no technical reason why it can't be there.