# Precompile AngularDart Templates

Tags: angularjs, dart

I used to work with Nodejs and AngularJS where I could precompile all the Angular's html templates into a single js file using https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates

I couldn't find anything similar for Dart and AngularDart. How could I make this work for the Dart version of Angular? Would I need to compile html to Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular.dart transformer does this to some degree by default.
All expressions in markup are evaluated and instead of reflection (used at development time) Dart code is generated so that no reflection is necessary in the deployed code.
The HTML templates are kept as HTML though.

The answer to this question stackoverflow.com/questions/25127598 contains more details about the `template cache generator`

Comment: What I don't like about keeping templates as HTML is that if my project is big there are going to be lots of http requests.

Comment: I see. I wondered myself already a while ago. I guess you should make a feature request in the [Angular.dart repo](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues) and wait for a repsonse. As I understand it, is performance very important to the Angular.dart team. I guess they already have a strategy how to handle this properly.

Comment: They have 143 open issues at the moment and this one is just 'nice to have' at this stage of v0.13.0. You're probably right about them having a strategy to handle this in the future, but I thought maybe someone hacked some temporary workaround.

Comment: See James' answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127598
I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure out how to use that. It looks like it's what I need so I'm accepting your answer. You should probably put link to that other SO question to your answer.